# Can curl output run a cmd command?

Tags: curl, cmd

So I curl my website and get output basically just, `curl website.net`
If i place `color a` in my website this command won't make cmd colored.

Is it possible to do that? If my curl output is = net view
I want my cmd window to run `net view` command.

Comment: Yes it is possible! ;) [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) should do

Comment: What do you mean by FOR/F ? When I only put color a in my website It only prints color a.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to process the output of a command in batch is to use [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). It will read the output of the command you gave it line by line and store (parts of) each line in loop variables. In your case:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('curl website.net') DO %%G
```

will read and execute each line of the output of the `curl website.net`.

**EDIT**: if you use it on the command line use `%G` instead of `%%G`